# How to remove the HTML content from a Page when Region is used in DXA 1.5 Java?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

We are trying to publish a `.txt` using a code Component by creating a Region and using a custom Page Template for `.txt` files.

Is there a way to remove the HTML tags that the Region is adding for my Page when I render `http://localhost:9080/dev/rb.txt`

```
<%-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="dxa" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-dxa"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="xpm" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-xpm"%>

<jsp:useBean id="pageModel" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.PageModel" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="markup" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request" />

<dxa:region name="MainBody" />
```

This is markup for the Region we are using and below is the Page with code Component.

[image]

I want to remove the `<html>` and the `<body>` tag from the source to render an raw text file. Could anyone suggest an approach for this?

Follow up question on this : [Render the Robots.txt using DXA 1.5 Java](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/17943/2147?sem=2)

Comment: Sounds like you have found an option to solve the other question then, in that case, please self answer that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bart says, DXA in general is designed to generate HTML, but in your case particularly the use of the `dxa:region` tag causes issues.

You could let the Page View output the content from the "Code Component" directly. For example, to get direct access to the first Entity Model in the "MainBody" Region, you can use this in your Page View: `pageModel.getRegions().get("MainBody").getEntities().get(0)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rick! This solution worked : `${pageModel.getRegions().get("MainBody").getEntities().get(0‌​).attribute}`

Comment: @SandeepDeshmukh, please consider accepting this answer if it answered your question. Up votes on helpful answers will also help and encourage community members to answer questions.

Answer (score 4):

It is a known issue that when you are trying to use empty Region views, you will get an additional `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tag generated, see https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/5

So currently that simply isn't possible, as DXA is basically designed to generate HTML.

The only quick option I could think of in solving this, is to look towards the generation of the configuration JSON files, which are published as a binary variant (which probably should be the answer also to [Render the Robots.txt using DXA 1.5 Java](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/17943)) .