# Remove the HTML and Body tags from the Page when the extension is not ".html"?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I am trying output `.json` files with Component data as its key value pairs. I avoided using regions to avoid `<div>` tags being inserted. I am pulling the entity fields values directly to the Page view but I still see `<html>` and `<body>` tags being added into Page. Is there a way to get these to go away if the o/p file extension is not `.html`?

Comment: it will be good if you can share some example.

Comment: I assume you're using a custom page controller for this? Care to share some of the code and approach you followed?

Answer (score 4):

Views are designed for generating HTML, if you wish to return JSON, you should not abuse the view technology for that (see also the answers to [How to remove the HTML content from a Page when Region is used in DXA 1.5 Java?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17954/how-to-remove-the-html-content-from-a-page-when-region-is-used-in-dxa-1-5-java/17955))

Have you tried requesting the URL of a page with `?format=json` added to it? Also take a look at `?format=atom` and `?format=rss`. I suggest to read up on the option of implementing a custom data format (in case the current JSON format is not usable for you), see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-DF3BDC77-0343-452F-BBB9-9CBA05021183

Comment: I did tried to use ?format=json but it has lot of information like xpm info/regions/entity details which we dont need.

Comment: I also look at the other post you mentioned it talks about avoiding the <div> tags that we get by using the regions.I already avoided them.
I opted my page template extension to be json, i expected valid json as o/p.It sounded like i need to have custom page controller to get different extension as o/p

Comment: Again please don’t try that unless you want more work than is needed, I have given you two viable options, use the JSON that is already there or add a custom data format instead